# Mysql - Right join not retrieving correct data

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I am storing the user activity in the table by start and end time , now i want to get all records from my subject table and matched records from log table.

This is my subject table

[image]

This is my log table

[image]

I want the output like this

[image]

I tried using some code but the records that only matched with log table is return as record, This is what i tried. Any help is appreciable.

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, A.start_time, A.end_time)) AS prep_time,
                B.subject_name,
                A.subject_id
            FROM prep_learn_log A
            RIGHT JOIN prep_subject B ON A.subject_id = B.subject_id 
                AND B.active = 'Y'
            WHERE A.user_id = '1' GROUP BY A.subject_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the where condition in the ON clause

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, A.start_time, A.end_time)) AS prep_time,
            B.subject_name,
            A.subject_id
        FROM prep_learn_log A
        RIGHT JOIN prep_subject B ON A.subject_id = B.subject_id 
            AND B.active = 'Y' AND A.user_id = '1' 
 GROUP BY A.subject_id
```

the use of right joined  column in where condition work as an inner join

Answer (score 1):

You can try below by putting `A.user_id = '1'`  in `On Clause`

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, A.start_time, A.end_time)) AS prep_time,
       B.subject_name,
       A.subject_id
       FROM prep_learn_log A
       RIGHT JOIN prep_subject B ON A.subject_id = B.subject_id 
       AND B.active = 'Y' and A.user_id = '1' 
       GROUP BY A.subject_id,B.subject_name
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

> `SELECT IFNULL(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(b.end_time,b.start_time)))),"00:00:00") AS prep_time,
>   a.subject_name,a.subject_id
>   FROM prep_subject a
>   LEFT JOIN prep_learn_log b ON a.subject_id = b.subject_id 
>   AND a.active = 'Y' GROUP BY a.subject_id ORDER BY a.subject_id;`
>
> I changed to LEFT JOIN and TIMEDIFF instead because I couldn't get TIMESTAMPDIFF working on my side.